# Twelve Distinct Positive Integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let *S* be a set of twelve distinct positive integers such that for distinct *a, b, c, and d* in *S*,

*a + b ≠ c + d*. Show that the largest element in *S* is greater than 56.

I found some math competition problems, and I am trying to work my way through them, but I am encountering difficulties. With this one, I am thinking that somehow it needs to be shown that if the largest number is ≤56 then we can find four distinct such that *a + b = c + d*. Then we have a contradiction.

Comment: Here's an approach. Instead of twelve numbers, start with four.  How small can the largest element be?  Once you figure that out, try five, six, etc.

Comment: Matthew Conroy's suggestions is basically what I did, which is just create a set with the smallest possible values that work. A fairly recognizable pattern emerges. I'm curious as why you need twelve elements in $S$ though. I'm getting the tenth one to be greater than $56$.

Comment: @JohnHabert - with $8$ elements of $S$, the maximum can be $30$, not $34$ as the sequence for smaller $S$ suggests. (Though I still get the 11th being greater than 56). And there's no obvious reason why the smaller elements of $S$ should be the smallest they can be either.

Comment: @user73985 True enough that they don't have to be the smallest but it is an easy place to start. Plus the way the pattern emerges gives some clue as to what is happening. Can you post your $8$ element set with max $30$?

Comment: $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 30\}$

Comment: $\{1,3,4,5,9,14,21,28\}$

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the obvious pattern breaks more in larger sets and so you need twelve numbers for this to work. I had only checked up to $21$.

Comment: Just for the reference, $\{1,2,3,5,9,15,20,25\}$ should be the optimal case for $n=8$ (i.e. there is no such distinct-sums-of-pairs set with $8$ elements, neither of which exceeds $24$). I also believe the bound is $58$ for $n=11$ and $72$ for $n=12$. These bounds were found using (hopefully exhaustive) search, so they might not admit an elegant proof; unlike the $56$ bound for $n=12$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the ${12 \choose 2} = 66$ possible differences $b-a$, where $b>a$ are the elements
of $S$.

Note that if $a, b, c, d \in S$ are pairwise distinct and $a-c = d-b$, then $a+b = c+d$.

Also, if
$a,b,c \in S$ are all distinct and $c-a = b-c$, then $c = (a+b)/2$ so $c$ is not the largest or smallest element of $S$.

Next, if $c-a = b -c$ and $c-d = e-c$, then $a+b = 2c = d+e$.  So for
each $c$, that is not the largest or smallest element of $S$, there exists at most one pair of $a, b$ that can be found such that $c-a=b-c$. Because if not, then we will have $a + b = d +e$.

Hence, there are at most $10$ duplicates for each $c$ that is not the largest or
smallest element of $S$.  Therefore, there are at least
$66 - 10 = 56$ distinct differences.

Hence, the largest element of $S$ is greater than 56.